# Python Memory Addresses: Variation Across Python 3.5 - 3.9 on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, memory-address

I stumbled upon a perplexing issue.  While trying to manually close out a XDisplay using `ctypes.CDLL("libX11.so")` to hot-fix VTK, I tried using the Python provided address of the XDisplay.  This worked fine on Python 3.8, but caused a segfault on Python 3.7.  Here's the code to demonstrate the problem of addressing the XDisplay created within VTK.  Specifically:

```py
disp_id = self.ren_win.GetGenericDisplayId()
disp_id_int = int(disp_id[1:].split('_')[0], 16)
print(disp_id, disp_id_int)
x11 = ctypes.CDLL("libX11.so")
x11.XCloseDisplay(disp_id_int)
```

Which, when run, returns:

```
user@host:~/tmp$ python3.7 tmp19.py
0000558f843c5930_p_void 94074887231792
Current thread 0x00007f8145824740 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/alex/python/pyvista/pyvista/plotting/plotting.py", line 2769 in close
  File "/home/alex/python/pyvista/pyvista/plotting/plotting.py", line 4207 in show

user@host:~/tmp$ python3.8 tmp19.py
0000000003568de0_p_void 56004064
```

As you can see, the address from Python 3.8 can be used with `libX11.so`, but not with Python 3.7 to close the XDisplay window.

As noted in the comments, the memory addresses returned from Python are always relative to the current Python process.  However, if this is the case, why do some version of Python appear to return very large addresses for `id(True)`, a structure created upon initialization of Python.  Even more perplexing, the versions of Python that return these large values also cause segmentation values when interfacing with the `"libX11.so"` library.

Here's the results for Python 3.5 - Python 3.9:

```
user@host:~$ python3.5 -c "print(id(True))"
93962585975264
user@host:~$ python3.6 -c "print(id(True))"
10302848
user@host:~$ python3.7 -c "print(id(True))"
94134164615424
user@host:~$ python3.8 -c "print(id(True))"
11498848
user@host:~$ python3.9 -c "print(id(True))"
11374464
```

---

Two questions:

- Is this expected behavior?  If so, I imagine there's a compiler flag that's been switched on/off for the version that I've installed locally.
- Is there a way to adjust the memory addresses to get a consistent result for all versions of Python?

Comment: The integer returned by `id()` happens to be the address on CPython, but that's an implementation detail. Can you show the actual code that's segfaulting?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do with the result of ``id``? The output of your commands does not only vary by version, but also by program run. Just rerunning the command gives different output!

Comment: "base_address of the current pid" is not a meaningful concept on any modern OS.  Every process runs in its own address space, with addresses starting at zero.

Comment: Edited to account for corrects from @jasonharper

Comment: If XCloseDisplay takes a pointer, passing an integer and not declaring `x11.XCloseDisplay.argtypes=ctypes.c_void_p,` as the parameter type will pass the value incorrectly on 64-bit systems.  ctypes assumes 32-bit integers for integer parameters unless told otherwise.  If 3.5 and 3.7 are returning >4GB addresses, that would explain it.

Comment: That's exactly it @MarkTolonen.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're depending on a [cpython implementation detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) that the `id(...)` function returns the memory address of the `PyObject`

in cpython, `Py_True` and `Py_False` are [macros, pointing at global instances of `bool` structs](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cc75ab791dd5ae2cb9f6e0c3c5f734a6ae1eb2a9/Include/boolobject.h#L20-L22):

```c
/* Use these macros */
#define Py_False ((PyObject *) &_Py_FalseStruct)
#define Py_True ((PyObject *) &_Py_TrueStruct)
```

the actual [definition of these structs](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cc75ab791dd5ae2cb9f6e0c3c5f734a6ae1eb2a9/Objects/boolobject.c#L202-L210):

```c
/* The objects representing bool values False and True */

struct _longobject _Py_FalseStruct = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyBool_Type, 0)
    { 0 }
};

struct _longobject _Py_TrueStruct = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyBool_Type, 1)
    { 1 }
};
```

the memory address of C globals is ~determined by the compiler, linker, and dynamic loader and depending on a constant value there is **undefined behaviour**

Comment: Thanks, and this is a good start that explains how ``id`` works and the likely reason for the variation between addresses, but I'd still like to know how to get the relative address for a given pointer relative to the base address of the python process.

Comment: @AlexKaszynski see the last sentence, what you're asking for is undefined

Comment: Yes, quite right, and I corrected the question to address that.  I'm still curious why the addresses given by Python 3.6, 3.8, and 3.9 can be used by libX11, but not 3.5 and 3.7.

Comment: dumb luck, most likely, given you're working with UB anything could happen

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the issue is with the pointer being > 4GB on my 64-bit Linux environment, which is incompatible with the default behavior when wrapping a library with ctypes.  Repeating a comment from @MarkTolonen:

> as the parameter type will pass the value incorrectly on 64-bit systems. ctypes assumes 32-bit integers for integer parameters unless told otherwise

The trick is to set the argtype as `c_void_p`:

```py
x11 = ctypes.CDLL("libX11.so")
x11.XCloseDisplay.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
x11.XCloseDisplay(disp_id_int)
```

The reason why this worked for me on Python 3.8 was address of the pointer happened to be small enough to be passed as an int32, while on Python 3.7 it just happened that the integer was too large for int32.  Instead, passing this as a `ctypes.c_void_p` fixed the issue.

Comment: BKM is to set `x11.XCloseDisplay.argtypes=c_void_p,` which actually declares the argument type, and you won't have to wrap your parameter each time you call XCloseDisplay.  Not setting argtypes/restype correclty is the #1 reason people have problems using ctypes.

Comment: Thanks again @MarkTolonen, I've updated my comment accordingly.